# align multiple sticky elements along a parent container

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an alignment along a div container with the following structure. There are 3 buttons and one `span` element but this could be replaced with other elements if needed.

[image]

I started creating this

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.todoContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.todoContent {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btnTodoAction {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 0;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #555555;
}

.todoIsCompleted>.todoContent {
  position: relative;
  color: #666666;
}

.todoIsCompleted>.todoContent::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #85bf6b;
}

.todoIsCompleted>.btnToggleTodoState {
  color: #85bf6b;
}
```

```html
<div class="todoContainer">
  <button class="btnTodoAction btnToggleTodoState">T</button>
  <span class="todoContent">Item 1</span>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">E</button>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">D</button>
</div>

<div class="todoContainer todoIsCompleted">
  <button class="btnTodoAction btnToggleTodoState">T</button>
  <span class="todoContent">Item 2</span>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">E</button>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">D</button>
</div>
```

and tried to add `float: right` to the buttons on the right side but they didn't stick to the right side.

How can I achieve it? (A solution using `display: grid` would be fine too)

Comment: I think you only need to add `flex-grow: 1` to your span. You should read up on flexbox. I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to be a helpful overview.

Comment: yes this seems to be a good solution but do you know how to fix the stroke line then? because this one will get as big as the container

Comment: If it's not going to be styled too fancy you could use `text-decoration: green line-through`. If you want to keep it in `:before` for more complex stuff you could put the actual text and the `:before` in a nested element. `span.todoContent > span.todoText:before`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code and here is what you expected , please have a look 
I have used `position` style to make it right aligned by placing two `button` in one div`<div class="pushRight">` and added styles for that `div`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222222;
}

.todoContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.todoContent {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.btnTodoAction {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 0;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #555555;
}
.pushRight{
  position: absolute;
  right:0
}

.todoIsCompleted>.todoContent {
  position: relative;
  color: #666666;
}

.todoIsCompleted>.todoContent::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #85bf6b;
}

.todoIsCompleted>.btnToggleTodoState {
  color: #85bf6b;
}
```

```html
<div class="todoContainer">
  <button class="btnTodoAction btnToggleTodoState">T</button>
  <span class="todoContent">Item 1</span>
  <div class="pushRight">
  <button class="btnTodoAction">E</button>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">D</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="todoContainer todoIsCompleted">
  <button class="btnTodoAction btnToggleTodoState">T</button>
  <span class="todoContent">Item 2</span>
   <div class="pushRight">
  <button class="btnTodoAction">E</button>
  <button class="btnTodoAction">D</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using float, check the [sample code](https://codepen.io/balajidesigner/pen/bOJdNp).

Here added `floating` instead `display:flex`

For right alignment added a class

`.pull-right{
  float:right;
}` 
and it will be called in

```
<button class="btnTodoAction pull-right">D</button>
<button class="btnTodoAction pull-right">E</button>
```